# How to validate if data is in sync post rebuild operation

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a cassandra cluster in dc-1 and now i have extended my cluster to dc-2 and expanded all the keyspaces, then ran

`nodetool rebuild dc-1`

on all the nodes in dc-2. Now is there a way i can verify if all the data from dc-1 is replicated to dc-2 ?

I am using 3.11.x version of cassandra

Answer (score 0):

If you have applications that constantly writing the data into Cassandra database, it's hard to do, as there always will be slight differences in data in both data centers, arising from data in flight, etc.

You can theoretically use Spark, with custom options to point to specific data center, and have a query that will load data up to some specific timestamp (based on the data inside database itself, so only on tables that have such field), and then compare two dataframes.

But frankly speaking, replication is the main functionality of Cassandra, and if you perform repairs regularly (it's recommended to use [Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/)), then you should have data in sync.